# how to test moq void methods

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I want to check whether call to method `Update` of object `RealtyObjectEntityRepository` was performed. I have the following method in my service:

```
public void UpdateRealtyObject(RealtyObjectDTO realtyObject)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> changedItems = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        RealtyObject before = this.unit.RealtyObjectRepository.GetById(realtyObject.RealtyObjectId);
        var realtyObjectEntity = Converter.FromDTO(realtyObject);
        this.unit.RealtyObjectRepository.Update(realtyObjectEntity);
    }
```

And I have written the test to test if method if the method was called:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void UpdateRealtyObject()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        var originalObject = new RealtyObject() { RealtyObjectId = 1, Description = "W", KOATUUId = "495857566455" };
        var updatedObject = new RealtyObject() { RealtyObjectId = 1, Description = "Wa", KOATUUId = "495857566456" };
        var mock = new Mock<RealtyObjectEntityRepository>();
        mock.Setup<RealtyObject>(x => x.GetById(originalObject.RealtyObjectId)).Returns(originalObject);
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<RealtyObject>>().Instance(mock.Object).LifeStyle.Transient);
        var service = new RealEstateService(container);
        service.UpdateRealtyObject(updatedObject.ToDTO());
        mock.Verify(m=>m.Update(updatedObject));

    }
```

However I've got exception that

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: m => m.Update(.updatedObject). No setups configured.

Could anybody suggest me what the problem is here?

Comment: Where does "this.unit" come from? You are making the test really complex for such a simple scenario because you are missusing dependency injection. The point of dependency injection is for the dependencies to be passed into the service when the service is created. The RealEstateService shouldn't know anything about the Windsor container.

Comment: This.unit points to unitOfWork class that is implemented as unit of work design pattern and contains all repositories. I will post this class soon.

Comment: You will need to mock the UoW so that it can provider your repository mock via the RealtyObjectRepository property.

Comment: Did you try to mock RealtyObjectRepository?